# Apple push notification setup error "unable to load Private Key"

Tags: openssl, apple-push-notifications

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) to build the push notification functionality. When I try the following line:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

It says:

```
unable to load Private Key
140735216849372:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Why don't you follow [Apple's instructions for generating the certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1)? If you follow these instructions, your `p12` file will contain both the private key and the certificate.

Comment: This one works! Thanks!

Comment: @Eran link is broken

Comment: @alizx well, it's been 8 years since I posted the comment. No wonder it's broken. Try Google to search for the current link.